# Download pdf file and save to sd card using Retrofit 1.9

Tags: android, retrofit, android-download-manager

API call is being carried out using Retrofit 1.9 library.   A feature require download .pdf file and save it to sd card. I tried to use Callback callback but getting error String cannot be cased to response body. The problem is am getting response in string format but i need to save the file to sd card. Any idea how can this be achieved using retrofit 1.9.

```
public interface ApiInterface {
        @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json", "Media-Type: application/json"})
        @GET("/user/statements")
        void getPDF(Callback<String> callback);
    }


getAsyncApi().getPDFResponse(new Callback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void success(String responseBody, retrofit.client.Response response) {
            retrofit.client.Response response1 = response;
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });
```

How can i save this pdf from response ?

Comment: `The problem is am getting response in string format`. That is wrong to begin with. You cannot put or receive a pdf file in a String variable. Strings are for text. You should try to receive the file as bytes.

Comment: yes and also from response.body